# Rails test error--- expected +++ actual

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Failure:
ProductTest#test_product_price_must_be_positive [/home/jatin/work/depot/test/models/product_test.rb:18]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-["must be geater than or equal to 0.01"]
+["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"]
```

This is the test code:

```
test "product price must be positive" do
product = Product.new( title: "My Book Title", description: "yyy", image_url: "zzz.jpg")
product.price = -1
assert product.invalid?
assert_equal ["must be geater than or equal to 0.01"], 
    product.errors[:price]

product.price = 0
assert product.invalid?
assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
    product.errors[:price]

product.price = 1
assert product.valid?
end
```

This is the code inside the app/models/product.rb file:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
validates :title, uniqueness: true
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
}
end
```

Please suggest a way to resolve this.

Comment: Did you look at the test failure? Did you compare the two strings?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo :

```
assert_equal ["must be geater than or equal to 0.01"], 
#                       ^ here
# Change to :
assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
```